# npm install -g angular-cli fails

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to install Angular CLI on linux. I type the command "npm install -g angular-cli" and I get this error:

> npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-36-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs"
>   "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli" npm ERR! node v4.2.6 npm
>   ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn
>
> npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.2 install: `node scripts/install.js` npm ERR!
>   spawn ENOENT npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.2 install
>   script 'node scripts/install.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the
>   latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this
>   is most likely a problem with the node-sass package, npm ERR! not with
>   npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js npm ERR! You can get information
>   on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   node-sass npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info
>   via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/matan/Projects/npm-debug.log npm ERR! code 1

I was looking for more info on the web, and I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: angular-cli is obsolete anyway. Read the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Also you should upgrade your node version, you can have multiple node versions with nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm